# Rails 5 LEFT OUTER JOIN includes records outside of condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, left-join

This is driving me crazy, and I'd like a separate pair of eyes on it. I have the following models:

```
class Client
  has_many: client_orders
end

class ClientOrders
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Now, I'm trying to get only orders for clients created in the past 30 days. So I write this:

```
time_range = (30.days.ago - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight
@clients = Client.left_outer_joins(:client_orders).where( client_orders: { created_at: time_range } )
```

I feel that logic is correct. Now, the following happens:

I write: `@clients.first.client_orders.first`

And the very first record is this:

```
=> #<ClientOrder:0x00007f364764b3b8
 id: 1,
 client_order_number: "25970",
 status: "pending",
 client_id: 3,
 client_user_id: 8,
 shipping_cost_cents: 287,
 shipping_cost_currency: "USD",
 taxes_cents: 8800,
 taxes_currency: "USD",
 created_at: Fri, 16 Feb 2018 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 31 Dec 2018 21:51:54 UTC +00:00,
 subtotal_cents: 3426500,
 subtotal_currency: "USD",
 quickbooks_id: nil,
 sync_token: nil,
 convenience_fee_cents: 0,
 convenience_fee_currency: "USD">
```

Notice the `created_at` date? Now, what's really funny, is if I do this:

```
@clients.first.client_orders.first.created_at === time_range
D, [2019-01-03T06:28:53.885281 #1] DEBUG -- :   CACHE ClientOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "client_orders".* FROM "client_orders" WHERE "client_orders"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY "client_orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-01-03T06:28:53.886633 #1] DEBUG -- :   ↳ (pry):7
=> false
```

So what the heck? Is there something in `erb` that does something funky so it's including records that shouldn't be when it actually runs or something? I've tried using other variables to store the query in in case it's including data from a previous query or something but that doesn't make a difference.

So, yeah, my goal is to an object that only contains the past 30 days worth of orders.

BONUS POINTS: Get the clients who DON'T have orders in the past 30 days. That I'm not quite sure about how to pull off. I was thinking something like this: `@clients = Client.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(client_id) FROM client_orders)')`

Comment: @clients.first.client_orders.first.created_at === time_range will not be true because where executes within query and you are trying to check equality.

Comment: time_range.include?(@clients.first.client_orders.first.created_at) try this it will be true. so the problem is in the === statement and has nothing to do with join

Comment: I tried that, and it still came out false:

[78] pry(#<AccountManagementsController>)> time_range.include?(@clients.first.client_orders.first.created_at) 
D, [2019-01-03T07:09:00.695526 #1] DEBUG -- :   CACHE ClientOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "client_orders".* FROM "client_orders" WHERE "client_orders"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY "client_orders"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-01-03T07:09:00.696902 #1] DEBUG -- :   ↳ (pry):46
=> false

Comment: another issue is in time_range = (30.days.ago - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight. try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I think you should declare something like these

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 30.days)..Time.now.midnight
@clients = Client.left_outer_joins(:client_orders).where( client_orders: { created_at: time_range } )
```

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what's happening. Is there a way I can reverse that query so it shows clients who don't have orders in that time frame?

Comment: Yes simply you can used @clients = Client.left_outer_joins(:client_orders).where.not( client_orders: { created_at: time_range } )

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work? I try this:

time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 30.days)..Time.now.midnight
    @clients = Client.left_outer_joins(:client_orders).where.not( client_orders: { created_at: time_range } ).distinct

And it still shows clients with orders in the past couple of days?

Comment: @JasonShultz please check your time zone format the same query does work for me